# Titan BluePrints Rexster

Tags: java, cassandra, titan, rexster

Revision:

I have a stand-alone version of Cassandra.  I launch that using the following command:

```
./cassandra -f
```

I also have a Java Application that the Titan Graph Library installed.  To obtain a TitanGraph object I use the following code:

```
BaseConfiguration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
configuration.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra");
configuration.setProperty("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1");
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(configuration);
```

After this I can add Vertices/Edges and Query them as well.  I did an additional check on the local Cassandra database and can verify there are records being generated and persisted

```
cqlsh> select count(*) from titan.edgestore;

 count
--------
 185050

(1 rows)
```

The problem arises when I launch the rexster-server.  I am launching this in stand-alone mode using the following command:

```
./rexster.sh -s -c ../config/rexster.xml
```

Then I launch the rexster console and load the graph.  The issues is that the graph seems to contain no data?  I am really not sure what is going on here.  There is only 1 instance of Cassandra running.

```
        (l_(l
(_______( 0 0
(        (-Y-) <woof>
l l-----l l
l l,,   l l,,
opening session [127.0.0.1:8184]
?h for help

rexster[groovy]> ?h
-= Console Specific =-
?<language-name>: jump to engine
?l: list of available languages on Rexster
?b: print available bindings in the session
?r: reset the rexster session
?e <file-name>: execute a script file
?q: quit
?h: displays this message

-= Rexster Context =-
rexster.getGraph(graphName) - gets a Graph instance
   :graphName - [String] - the name of a graph configured within Rexster
rexster.getGraphNames() - gets the set of graph names configured within Rexster
rexster.getVersion() - gets the version of Rexster server

rexster[groovy]> rexster.getGraphNames() 
==>kpdlp
rexster[groovy]> rexster.getGraph('graph')
==>titangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]]
rexster[groovy]> g = rexster.getGraph('graph')
==>titangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]]
rexster[groovy]> g.V.count()
==>0
rexster[groovy]>
```

Below is the rexster.xml I am using

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rexster>
    <http>
        <server-port>8182</server-port>
        <server-host>0.0.0.0</server-host>
        <base-uri>http://localhost</base-uri>
        <web-root>public</web-root>
        <character-set>UTF-8</character-set>
        <enable-jmx>false</enable-jmx>
        <enable-doghouse>true</enable-doghouse>
        <max-post-size>2097152</max-post-size>
        <max-header-size>8192</max-header-size>
        <upload-timeout-millis>30000</upload-timeout-millis>
        <thread-pool>
            <worker>
                <core-size>8</core-size>
                <max-size>8</max-size>
            </worker>
            <kernal>
                <core-size>4</core-size>
                <max-size>4</max-size>
            </kernal>
        </thread-pool>
        <io-strategy>leader-follower</io-strategy>
    </http>
    <rexpro>
        <server-port>8184</server-port>
        <server-host>0.0.0.0</server-host>
        <session-max-idle>1790000</session-max-idle>
        <session-check-interval>3000000</session-check-interval>
        <read-buffer>65536</read-buffer>
        <enable-jmx>false</enable-jmx>
        <thread-pool>
            <worker>
                <core-size>8</core-size>
                <max-size>8</max-size>
            </worker>
            <kernal>
                <core-size>4</core-size>
                <max-size>4</max-size>
            </kernal>
        </thread-pool>
        <io-strategy>leader-follower</io-strategy>
    </rexpro>
    <shutdown-port>8183</shutdown-port>
    <shutdown-host>127.0.0.1</shutdown-host>
    <config-check-interval>10000</config-check-interval>
    <script-engines>
        <script-engine>
            <name>gremlin-groovy</name>
            <reset-threshold>-1</reset-threshold>
            <init-scripts>config/init.groovy</init-scripts>
            <imports>com.tinkerpop.rexster.client.*</imports>
            <static-imports>java.lang.Math.PI</static-imports>
        </script-engine>
    </script-engines>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <type>none</type>
            <configuration>
                <users>
                    <user>
                        <username>rexster</username>
                        <password>rexster</password>
                    </user>
                </users>
            </configuration>
        </authentication>
    </security>
    <metrics>
        <reporter>
            <type>jmx</type>
        </reporter>
        <reporter>
            <type>http</type>
        </reporter>
        <reporter>
            <type>console</type>
            <properties>
                <rates-time-unit>SECONDS</rates-time-unit>
                <duration-time-unit>SECONDS</duration-time-unit>
                <report-period>10</report-period>
                <report-time-unit>MINUTES</report-time-unit>
                <includes>http.rest.*</includes>
                <excludes>http.rest.*.delete</excludes>
            </properties>
        </reporter>
    </metrics>
    <graphs>
<graph>
    <graph-name>graph</graph-name>
    <graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
    <graph-location></graph-location>
    <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
    <properties>
          <storage.backend>cassandrathrift</storage.backend>
          <storage.hostname>127.0.0.1</storage.hostname>
    </properties>
    <extensions>
      <allows>
        <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
      </allows>
    </extensions>
  </graph>
    </graphs>
</rexster>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is just some confusion in Rexster's role.  Your question was:

> My issue is that when I instantiate an TitanGraph using the
>   TitanFactory as seen below there does not seem to be the option to
>   specify the graph name?

Note that using `TitanFactory` will open a `TitanGraph` instance that connects directly to cassandra.  That has nothing to do with Rexster.  If you want to connect to Rexster (which remotely holds a `TitanGraph` instance given your configuration) then you must do so through REST or RexPro.  With the more simple approach for verifying operations being REST, try to curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8182/graphs
```

That should return some JSON that contains the name of the `TitanGraph` instance you configured in the `<graph-name>` field in `rexster.xml`.  The `<graph-name>` simply identifies the graph instance in Rexster so that you can uniquely identify it in requests when there are multiple instances hosted in there.

Comment: That makes sense.  So the name in the Rexster Graph has nothing to do with connecting to the Graph, it is the unique key to access that instance that Rexster connects to via the API?  That helps a lot.  I am still having an issue that the data I am generating in my Java app is not showing up when I connect via Rexster.

Comment: can you do the reverse?  from rexster console, add a vertex/commit and then try to see if you can access it from the `TitanGraph` instance in your application code (or the Gremlin Console).  More often than not, problems like this have to do with with either not committing the transaction or with pointing at the wrong database instance somehow.  It sounds like you verified that neither of those things is your problem, but worth reviewing again.

Comment: I saw this error in the rexster-server: Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):6534, latency=10004(10004), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection    I am using the latest version of cassandra.  Could it be an issues connecting to Cassandra?  The weird thing is that in gremlin even though I cannot see the data from the Java app I can still create vertexes and edges and they seem to persist.  They do not appear to be stored in the cassandra database.